# $\mathrm{Bessel}^3$ Integral

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, integration, quantum-mechanics, integral-transforms, bessel-functions

I'm trying to calculate the following integral:
$\int_0^\infty \mathrm{BesselJ}[l_0,k_0r] \cdot \mathrm{BesselJ}[l_1,k_1r] \cdot \mathrm{BesselJ}[l_0-l_1,kr] \cdot r\,dr$

($\mathrm{BesselJ}[n,x]$ is the Bessel function of the first kind of order $n$)
I assume that $l_0,l_1$ are integers, and that $k_0,k_1,k>0$.

The result has nice implications in quantum mechanics - to explain selection rules.

I was able to prove that the integral is zero when $k,k_0,k_1$ cannot be the lengths of a triangle.
So there is a non-zero result when $|k_0-k_1| < k < k_0+k_1$
However, I don't know how to calculate the integral when it is not zero.
Can anyone help?

I tried using Mathematica to get a numerical answer (which is fine for me), but I do not think I can count on it. Mathematica is giving a non-zero result for the regime where the integral should be zero.

Comment: You should look up Watson's book: pages [411-412](https://archive.org/stream/treatiseontheory00watsuoft#page/411) have a very similar vanishing theorem, plus resulting 3-fold product integrals evaluated in terms of the area $\Delta$ of your triangle. (In particular when $l_0=l_1=0$ the integral is $1/2\pi\Delta$.)

Comment: And when $l_0=l_1=n$, the cited paper of [MacDonald](http://books.google.com/books?id=tPYOAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA142) (p. 144) gives the result in a nicer form than both Watson (p. 412) and Auluck (eq. 17):$$\int_0^\infty J_n(ar)J_n(br)J_0(cr)r\,dr=\begin{cases}0 &\text{if } c^2<(a-b)^2\\\dfrac{\cos(nC)}{\pi ab\sin C} &\text{if }c^2 = a^2+b^2-2ab\cos C\\0&\text{if }c^2>(a+b)^2\end{cases}$$ where I have used that $P^{\frac12}_{n-\frac12}(\cos C) = \sqrt{\frac 2{\pi\sin C}}\cos(nC)$.

Comment: It looks like the results of this investigation have now appeared in [Phys. Rev. X](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevX.6.011006).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In fact, precisely your integral has been computed in closed form, in: Annie Gervois and Henri Navelet, [*Some integrals involving three Bessel functions when their arguments satisfy the triangle inequalities*](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=761861), J. Math. Phys. 25 (1984), no. 11, 3350–3356. Their result is
$$
\int_0^\infty J_m(ar)J_n(br)J_{m+n}(cr)r\,dr =
\begin{cases}
0&\text{if }c^2 < (a-b)^2\\
\dfrac{\cos(mB-nA)}{\pi ab\sin C}&\text{if }c^2 = a^2+b^2-2ab\cos C\\
0&\text{if }c^2 > (a+b)^2
\end{cases}
$$
where in the second case, $A, B, C$ are the angles opposite to sides $a, b, c$ of the resulting triangle. (They give formulas valid for real $m, n$, which reduce to the above when $m, n\in\mathbf Z$ as you assume.)

To put this in your notation, take $(m,n,a,b,c)=(l_0,-l_1,k_0,k_1,k)$ and use that $A+B+C=\pi$ and $J_n=(-1)^nJ_{-n}$. We get
$$
\int_0^\infty J_{l_0}(k_0r)J_{l_1}(k_1r)J_{l_0-l_1}(kr)r\,dr =
\begin{cases}
0&\text{if }k < |k_0-k_1|\\
\dfrac{\cos([l_0-l_1]K_1-l_1K)}{\pi k_0k_1\sin K}&\text{if }|k_0-k_1|<k<|k_0+k_1| \\
0&\text{if }k > |k_0+k_1|
\end{cases}
$$
where $K_0,K_1,K$ are the angles opposite to $k_0,k_1,k$. The denominator is $2\pi$ times the triangle's area.

Comment: This is even better than I expected!
So beautiful that there is an exact analytic solution.
Thank you

Comment: @Mikhael I agree, that formula is pretty cool. Glad you sent me looking for it. By the way, I'm curious about your application. Could you post links to it (or background) if/when available?

Answer (score 10):

This triple-Bessel integral was studied in much detail by S.K.H. Auluck, [On the Integral of the Product of Three Bessel Functions over an Infinite Domain](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/data/uploads/2013/01/Auluck.pdf). Closed form expressions are given if two the three orders coincide. For the more general case, a reliable way to evaluate this integral using `Mathematica` is described and tested. The numerical difficulties arise because the integral diverges when $k\rightarrow|k_0\pm k_1|$.

When considered as a function of $k_0,k_1,k$, the triple-Bessel integral is sharply peaked at $k\rightarrow|k_0\pm k_1|$, and can be approximated (in the sense of a distribution) by a sum of delta functions at these points:

[image]

Applying that to your special case (where one order is the sum of the other two orders), I arrive at the following delta-function approximation:

$$\int_0^\infty \mathrm{BesselJ}[l_0,k_0r] \cdot \mathrm{BesselJ}[l_1,k_1r] \cdot \mathrm{BesselJ}[l_0-l_1,kr] \cdot r\,dr\approx$$

$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{k_1 k}}\left[\delta(k_0-k_1-k)+(-1)^{l_0-l_1}\delta(k_0-k_1+k)H(k_1-k)+(-1)^{l_1}\delta(k_0-k+k_1)H(k-k_1)\right]$$

Comment: Thanks for the help.
I found both the special case by Francois Ziegler and the approximation of the full problem by Carlo Beenakker very helpful.